# Definition of CM form

Tags: modular-arithmetic, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

Could someone please tell me how we define CM modular form and non-CM modular forms in the most basic way?Also, could you provide the references to your definition?
I have tried searching for the definition. But still the definition is not clear to me.

Comment: See the answers to this MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121688/definition-of-cm-modular-form